# Spark + Kafka integration : basedir must be absolute: ?/.ivy2/local

Tags: apache-spark

I use the Structured Streaming Kafka + Spark integration. I have the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: basedir must be absolute: ?/.ivy2/local
```

I tried to look for Ivy details in my `spark-master` container but I could not find any files related to Ivy except from a jar file. I also tried to point `spark.jars.ivy` at the folder were the Ivy jar was located but that would not work as well. I'm not really sure to understand what is Ivy's job and how it is related to Spark. If you can enlighten me on that, that would be really helpful.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes

  kafka-broker:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.3
    hostname: kafka-broker
    container_name: kafka-broker
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.4.1
    container_name: spark-master
    environment:
      - JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 7077:7077
      - 4040:4040
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/spark-entrypoint.sh:/scripts/spark-entrypoint.sh
      - ./data:/data
    entrypoint: /scripts/spark-entrypoint.sh

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.4.1
    container_name: spark-worker
    environment:
      - JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

And here is my `spark-entrypoint.sh` script :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pip install -r "/scripts/requirements.txt"
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1 --conf spark.jars.ivy="/tmp" ws.py
```

Comment: Ivy downloads JARs from Maven central since you've added --packages. It's also the worker that uses ivy, not the master

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really dumb : I needed to make sure that I was passing arguments in the right order to `spark-submit`.

`spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1 --conf spark.jars.ivy="/tmp" <myscript>.py`

and not :

`spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1 <myscript>.py --conf spark.jars.ivy="/tmp"`